# Convergent Subsequences of Dyadic Rationals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For consistency of definitions, I'll specify a particular set of dyadic rationals as follows: For an integer $n \geq 0$, let $D_n$ be the subset of $[0, 1]$ consisting of all points $d = \frac{a_0}{2^0} + \frac{a_1}{2^1} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{2^n}$, where each $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n$ is either 0 or 1. A number $d$ in $[0, 1]$ is said to be dyadic if it belongs to $D_n$ for some $n$. Let $D$ be the set of all dyadic numbers in $[0, 1]$.

Now, we consider a sequence of all distinct points in $D$ (i.e. some sequence $\{d_n\}$ such that every point in $D$ appears once). Does $\{d_n\}$ necessarily have a subsequence that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$? My intuition is yes, but I'm trying to justify this rigorously. I know that $D$ is dense in $[0,1]$, and I want to use this fact, but I'm having trouble specifying the form of such a subsequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $n_1$ such that $|d_{n_1}-\frac 1 2| <1$. Then choose $n_2 >n_1$ such that $|d_{n_2}-\frac 1 2| <\frac  1 n$. [ If there is no such $n_2$ the sequence $(d_n)$ won't be dense: the interval $(\frac 1  2 -\frac  1 2  ,\frac 1  2 +\frac  1 2)$ would have only finitely many points forn $(d_n)$.]. By induction we get $n_1<n_2<...$ with $|d_{n_k}-\frac 1 2| <\frac  1 k$. This gives a subsequence converging to $\frac 1 2$.